# Javascript treats my csv numerical data as string

Tags: javascript, php, file

Why does javascript concatenate the numeric data I imported via csv file?  My data file is a single-column string of numerical data (as defined in Excel) with no special characters or delimiters. Viewed in Notepad, the data appears to be numerical.  When I php-echo the variables representing this data, they appear to be numerical.  But when I added them, javascript concatenates the two numbers into a single string.  I performed floatval() and intval() on the variables which returned 0s.  Why is this data behaving like a string?

A sample of my code is shown below.  Any help/advice you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Please be gentle--this is my first-every html project.  Thanks in advance.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$V_team_index = $_POST["visitSelect"];
$H_team_index = $_POST['homeSelect'];

echo "<br>";

$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('DPI_Data_Grab.csv')); // Tried
/*$array = file('DPI_Data_Grab.csv');*/

$H_Offense_yrds = $array[$H_team_index + 390];
$V_Offense_yrds = $array[$V_team_index + 390];

/*$V_Offense_yrds = intval($V_Offense_yrds);  // Both Return 0
$H_Offense_yrds = intval($H_Offense_yrds);*/

/*$V_Offense_yrds = floatval($V_Offense_yrds);  // Both Return 0
$H_Offense_yrds = floatval($H_Offense_yrds);*/

echo "<br>";
echo "Home Team Offensive Yards: " .$H_Offense_yrds;
echo "<br>";
echo "Visiting Team Offensive Yards: " .$V_Offense_yrds;
echo "<br>";
?>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var V_Offense_yrds = <?php echo json_encode($V_Offense_yrds); ?>;
var H_Offense_yrds = <?php echo json_encode($H_Offense_yrds); ?>;
var Total;

Total = V_Offense_yrds + H_Offense_yrds;

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = V_Offense_yrds;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = H_Offense_yrds;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = Total;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hint. what's the js concatenation symbol ??

Comment: The values are strings in the PHP context, especially since the code to convert them to numbers is commented out. Thus the PHP `json_encode()` calls are dropping a JavaScript string constant into the JavaScript code, so the values are strings in JavaScript too.

Comment: You could always punt and do `Total = parseInt( V_Offense_yrds ) + parseInt( H_Offense_yrds );`  ...  ;-)

Comment: The text in csv is always a string, and the text in html is also a string. It can only be a number in json, php or javascript, if you convert to it.